# Use Paypal as a merchant bank account to receive money from google

Tags: paypal, in-app-purchase, payment

I have an google devenloper account and just upload a game to google play store, my game has in app purchase funcion. Can i receive in app purchase monney form my game through verify paypal account? In payment setting i see google only accecpted merchant bank account. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. How exactly does Unity3d connect to this?